# serializing form data with query.serializeJSON

Tags: jquery

I have followed previous answers to transform the form data to JSON using  [this package](https://github.com/marioizquierdo/jquery.serializeJSON)

```
<main>



<form id="myform" action="/form" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
email: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
message: <input type="text" name="message"><br>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>



<div id='response'></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.serializeJSON/2.9.0/jquery.serializejson.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('#myform').serializeJSON();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am sure I am missing something trivial. I need the data passed with post to /form to be JSON and this is not the case with the aboce code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with your code. I tried entering it into snippet and it works just fine.

I only changed your `<main>` into `<html><body>`

```html
<html>
<body>


<form id="myform" action="/form" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="namevalue"><br>
email: <input type="text" name="email" value="emailvalue"><br>
message: <input type="text" name="message" value="messagevalue"><br>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>



<div id='response'></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.serializeJSON/2.9.0/jquery.serializejson.min.js"></script>
<script>
//console.log($('#myform').serializeJSON());
$("#myform").submit(function(){
  console.log($('#myform').serializeJSON());
  
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://webhook.site/9b058239-03ad-49d2-9e0e-6c6be1bfe20b",
    data: JSON.stringify($('#myform').serializeJSON()),
    success: function(data){alert("success posting!"+data);},
    error: function(data){alert("error posting!"+data);},
    contentType: "application/json"
  });
  return false;
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit:
I used webhook.site to test the POST'ed JSON. It works as expected.

Here it is (it works with the snippet): https://webhook.site/#!/9b058239-03ad-49d2-9e0e-6c6be1bfe20b/01154f2c-ac5b-426d-b68c-5959e6bf9941/1

If you can't read the data on server side, please check if you have added `Content-Type: application/json` header, and set request type to `POST`

Comment: @kiristian this works in the console but nothing is passed as a post once I click submit :(

Comment: @devnull all the form data are passed once I click submit, see my edit. You might forget to add ```Content-Type: application/json``` header, or forget to change the request type to ```POST```